How many permutations of [26] have exactly 24 cycles?
How many permutations of [26] have exactly 24 cycles?
My idea for this would be to use the Stirling numbers of the first kind formula:
$$ ^nC_k = \ ^{n-1} C_{k-1} + (n-1) \ ^{n-1}C_k$$
but this would take forever, and may not even be correct.
Is there a recursive formula that I am missing out on?
Thanks.

Do you know how to count the number of permutations of $[26]$ with 26 cycles?  How about 25 cycles?  The case of 24 cycles is not much more work to do by hand.

As suggested by the comment, this is a case that can be done by inspection.
The number of trivial cycles (fixed points) can obviously not be larger than or equal to $24$. It can also not be smaller than $22$, for the maximum number of total cycles obtainable with exactly $N$ trivial cycles is $N + \left\lfloor \frac{1}{2} (26 - N) \right\rfloor$ (can you see why?).
In particular, I claim that the permutations of $[26]$ with exactly $24$ cycles consist only of permutations that involve exactly

$23$ trivial cycles (and a single non-trivial cycle of size $3$), or
$22$ trivial cycles (and two non-trivial cycles, both of size $2$).

These are easy to count. For the first case, you select the $3$ elements involved in the non-trivial cycle, and for each such selection, there are $2$ permutations (say we picked $A, B, C$; then the two possible permutations are $(ABC)$ and $(ACB)$). For the second case, you select the $4$ elements involved in the non-trivial cycles. For each such selection, there are $3$ permutations (say we picked $A, B, C, D$; then the three possible permutations are $(AB)(CD)$, $(AC)(BD)$, and $(AD)(BC)$).
So, the desired count is
$$2 \binom{26}{3} + 3 \binom{26}{4} = \boxed{50050}$$
